# turn maze / tilt maze generation algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, maze, tilt

```
**I have generated maze using dfs. I followed this alogorithm 

create a CellStack (LIFO) to hold a list of cell locations  
set TotalCells = number of cells in grid  
choose a cell at random and call it CurrentCell  
set VisitedCells = 1  

while VisitedCells < TotalCells 
find all neighbors of CurrentCell with all walls intact   
if one or more found 
choose one at random  
knock down the wall between it and CurrentCell  
push CurrentCell location on the CellStack  
make the new cell CurrentCell  
add 1 to VisitedCells
else 
pop the most recent cell entry off the CellStack  
make it CurrentCell
endIf
endWhile  

Now I need to generate a Tilt/Turn  Maze in which you can turn the maze left or right. Once you turn the maze , ball will start falling due to gravity until it hits a barrier. There is no way you can stop the ball in middle of its fall.
what I have found till now is few maze designs but nothing on tilt/turn maze generation algorithm.
what I have tried - 
Take a grid of nxn
take a start point for ball.
take a end point (hole). 
fill the remaining cell of maze with blocks.
while (ball do not reach the hole){
randomly turn the maze to left or right
take a random fall
remove the blocks in path 
}
```

It worked for small mazes but for bigger mazes it is going infinite loop (stack overflow)
  And how can I increase and decrease the complexity of this maze in same grid size.
**

Comment: From a brief look over the description, only the number of visited cells seems to be counted, but there is no information stored if a specific cell is visited.

Comment: whole maze is a 2D array. So I am maintaining all information about  ball position , hole position,path(visited cells), blocks (unvisited cells)